# How to change the 'start' and 'end' parameter sent by ajax in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, fullcalendar

Here is the request URL for JSON data through Ajax:

```
'/php/get-events.php?start=2015-05-31&end=2015-06-07&_=1433154089490'.
```

So it will return the `JSON data from 2015-05-31 to 2015-06-07`.

However I want to retrieve data in larger time range (may be for more than a month or a year).

Therefore, I need to change the Ajax parameter 'start' and 'end'.

The fullcalendar docs suggest using `'startParam' and 'endParam'` but it doesn't work, even I set it as `(YYYY-MM-DD)` format or `UNIX timestamp` format.

How to change the 'start' and 'end' parameter in fullcalendar?

Thanks for any help.

Updated:

```
function show() {
    var events = {
        url: 'php/get-events.php',
        data: {
            q:"", // my parameter
            code: "", // my parameter
            startDate: '2014-08-08', //fullcalendar parameter
            endDate: '2015-08-08', // fullcalendar parameter
        },
        success: function (JS){

        },
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
}
```

The fullcalendar automatically generates 'start' and 'end' parameters for every view (start day and end day of the view). I need to change these to retrieve a wider time range data (for example: more than a year).

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Which view are you using? Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help understanding the problem.

Comment: @A1rPun help me please

Comment: You have control over the ajax request right? Why don't you change the start & end params yourself?

Comment: @A1rPun Of course, I control over ajax request. But the fullcalendar automatically generate the start and end param. I try to change them but it does not work.

Comment: @ibrahimozil06: did you get anywhere with solving this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to change the param names? I believe changing the `startParam`a and `endParam` won't work, those only allow you to change the params the are sent with the request, which by default are `start` and `end`.

One way to is to create a custom view, otherwise here's a solution for existing default views. First set a global `start` and `end` param names that you can control, such as:

```
window.fc_startParam = 'startDate';
window.fc_endParam = 'endDate';
```

Then you have to modify the JS objects within `success`, such as:

```
function show() {
    var events = {
        url: 'php/get-events.php',
        data: {
            q:"", // my parameter
            code: "", // my parameter
            startDate: '2014-08-08', //fullcalendar parameter
            endDate: '2015-08-08', // fullcalendar parameter
        },
        success: function (data){
            var events = Object
                .keys(data)
                .map(function(key) {
                    return data[key];
                })
                .map(function(post, index) {

                    var json = {
                        q: post.q,
                        code: post.code,
                        start: post[window.fc_startParam]
                        end: post[window.fc_endParam]
                    }

                    return json;

                });

            return events;

        },
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
}
```